# Why is the word "arranged" wrong in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Prices **arranged** from under ten dollars to over a thousand.

Can it rewrite to "prices **are arranged** from under ten dollars to over a thousand"?

Comment: It looks like an error where the writer really meant 'ranged'. We would not use 'arranged' like that.

Comment: So, do you mean to use "ranged" to replace "arranged"?

Comment: I mean exactly that.

Comment: You would use *are* only if you meant to use *arrange*.  For example, prices *are arranged/sorted* from lowest to highest.  Those prices *range* from under ten dollars to over a thousand.  Things *are arranged* by type (thinnest to thickest, slowest to fastest, tallest to shortest).  Things *range* from the greatest to least, or visa versa, of what is being considered (.5 mm thick to 6 cm thick, 2 kph to 100 kph, 3 meters high to 14 meters high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence looks like the writer really meant 'ranged', the past tense of the verb 'range'. We would not use 'arranged' like that.

> **range  verb**
>
> to have an upper and a lower limit in amount, number, etc.
>
> *Dress sizes range from petite to extra large.*
> *Prices range between $50 and $250.*

[Range (verb) Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/range)